# How to HTML encode contents of a div in jQuery for use in Ace editor?

Tags: jquery, html-encode, ace-editor

**Goal**

Change content of a div into HTML encoded content for use in Ace editor.

**Attempted Solution**

I am trying to follow the solution here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1219983/1063287

With:

**HTML**

```
<div id="encode_me"><html>test</html></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
my_value = $("#encode_me");
$('<div/>').text(my_value).html();
```

**jsFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/3bFKG/8/

It is just outputting the text `test`.

**Edit:**  Alternatively, there is a [newer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7124052/1063287) on that page that suggests:

```
function htmlEscape(str) {
    return String(str)
        .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
        .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
        .replace(/'/g, '&#39;')
        .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
        .replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}
```

And I tried to implement that in a jsFiddle with the same results as the first attempt:

**HTML**

```
<div id="encode_me"><html>test</html></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
my_value = $("#encode_me");

my_value.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;').replace(/'/g, '&#39;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
```

**jsFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/6n2fR/

Comment: Did you try http://stackoverflow.com/a/7124052/1561971 ?

Comment: I referred to that in the post and created a jsFiddle based on it here - http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/6n2fR/ , I got the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into lots of problems when trying to implement this.

Basically `<html>` tags were always stripped out and I couldn't find a way to *access* the html markup before the tags were stripped or to encode the html within the div containing the markup.  jQuery's `text()` and `html()` and various combinations of them did not work.

**Solution**

This was the solution that eventually worked for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/rAFSZ/1/

**HTML**

```
<div id="my_html"></div>

<!-- this works using <xmp> tags and NOT when using <div> tags -->

<xmp id="my_html_hidden"><html>test</html></xmp>
```

**jQuery**

The approach I used was to set the value like this:

```
var html_editor = ace.edit("my_html");
// other editor settings
html_editor.session.setValue($("#my_html_hidden").text());
```

So the logic of this is that the content was loaded into a hidden div from the database, and then the value of the editor was set with the contents of this hidden div, with the `text()` method applied.

The key was that using `<xmp>` tags did NOT strip the `<html>` tags, whereas using `<div>` tags did.

Comment: This isn't a solution, try showing contents of your answer or simply `</xmp><script>alert("Hello XSS")</script>`

Answer (score 1):

A few major issues with your code.  Here's what I did that [works](http://jsfiddle.net/3bFKG/6/):

#### HTML

```
<div id="encode_me"><div>test</div></div>
```

#### JS

```
my_value = document.getElementById("encode_me").innerHTML;
my_value = $('<div/>').text(my_value).html();
$('div').text(my_value);
```

- You can't have `<html>` as a tag.  It gets ignored.  Replace it with `<div>`, and you can then get innerHTML.
- You can avoid jQuery as I did, or use it as `my_value = $("#encode_me")[0].innerHTML`;
- For the selector to change the text, just look for a div, not a div end tag with the `<>`.

Looking through the answer you reference, the `$('<div/>')` stuff is used to create a new div that isn't added to the DOM, and use that for the HTML manipulation.  After getting the `innerHTML`, I use that trick to encode the parts that need encoding.  (If there was a text node inside the div, [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML) would automagically convert that, but since it's all standard divs, it doesn't.)

Unfortunately, the [`<html>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/html) tag is only used "as the root element of a document, or wherever a subdocument fragment is allowed in a compound document."  I expect `innerHTML` to emit that tag properly if its use is standards-conforming, but the example in your fiddle was not.

Comment: The Ace editor displays HTML code which may sometime include the `<HTML></HTML>` tags.  Is it not possible at all to show these tags?  Also, the content needs to be HTML encoded ie `<html>test</html>` should be `&lt;html&gt;test&lt;/html&gt;`. That functionality is achieved in the code from the referred post through functions (http://jsbin.com/ejuru/1/edit), and I'm trying to do it without functions.

Comment: @user1063287 I answered these issues to the best of my abilities in my edited answer.